# A complex Lisp issue

Tags: lisp

Define a function `contains` that takes two parameters, a symbol A and a list of symbols L, and returns t only if L contains A as one of its elements.

That is the original question. I am very new to LISP and would like some code along with an explanation of the syntax. Coming from a java and C++ background LISP is very different in nature. Please help.

So far my code successfully takes two inputs as an parameter.

Pseudocode:
I compare the value in A with the first Value of the List then pass the list and variable A back into the function with a recursive call until the the List is empty. If the List is empty return null.

The issue with this is if List contains the a nested List how do i recognize the nested loop.

Such as: `(contains #\b '(a (((b))) c))` -> must print true.

So Far What I Have Code:

```
(defun contains (a list)
    (if (eq a(car list))
        (princ "t")
        (contains a (cdr list))))

(contains  #\B '(B a c d e f g))
```

I need a way for detecting at the end of the list. And a way to search inside nested lists.

Comment: I assume you're not allowed to use the standard `MEMBER` function?

Comment: The question doesn't require you to go into nested lists.

Comment: Unfortunatly no, I am only allowed to use Primitive function such as defun, car cdr cons if

Comment: The problem definition says that `L` is a list of symbols. `(a (((b))) c)` is not a list of symbols, it's a list of a symbol, a list, and another symbol.

Comment: That is an example list. The function is too also scan nested Lists for the variable then jump back out to the outer list and continue scanning the outer List. It must scan any and all nested Lists also.

Comment: Please update the question with the exact problem statement. And show the code you've tried to write. We're not here to do your homework for you. Once you post your code, we can point out where you went wrong, and that's how you learn.

Comment: I think it would be appropriate to modify the title of your question, reflecting the actual problem you're trying to solve. "A complex LISP issue" can mean many things to many people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let's fix some your mistakes: `#\b` isn't a SYMBOL, it's a CHARACTER, as I understand we looking for symbol in a list of symbols, so we don't need to do some character -> symbol conversion. Second: don't `(princ t)` just return t.

My short variant:

```
(defun contains (sym nested-list)
  "Find if NESTED-LIST contains a SYM"
  ;; Check if our list is CONS-cell?.
  (if (consp nested-list)
    ;; Recursion on cars and cdrs
    (or (contains sym (car nested-list))
        (contains sym (cdr nested-list)))
    ;; Elseway just check for equality
    (eq sym nested-list)))

CL-USER> (contains 'a '(b c (x b y (f a)) d))
T
CL-USER> (contains 'w '(b c (x b y (f a)) d))
NIL
```

On your test-case too:

```
CL-USER> (contains 'b '(a (((b))) c))
T
```

Comment: What does the keyword consp do?

Comment: @AdityaNishtala, i added some comments to code, `CONSP` checks if it's argument a CONS-CELL. So we basicly going through list. If we have a nested list, we going inside it, if we have an atom here, we just checking for equality with our symbol. And `consp` insn't a keyword, it's just a function.